# Intellij unable to find classes while running Ivy Project

Tags: intellij-idea, ivy

I have imported an Ivy Project in Intellij. I am using IvyIdea plugin. I also have ivy-settings.xml in place. I am able to successfully build the project. When I am deploying my application on jetty server, I am getting this error. Basically it's unable to find all my libraries.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

I guess, this means that my libaries are not present in the classpath and I confirmed in "Project Structure" -> Dependencies -> IvyIdea and I can see all the jars there.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you [add the libraries to the artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) that you are deploying?

Comment: I don't add libraries manually for Maven Project. Why do I need to do it for Ivy?How do I add this?

Comment: When importing a Maven project IntelliJ IDEA generates the artifact with the dependencies. Ivy plug-in developer has probably not implemented this feature. The link in my first comment explains how you can add dependencies to the artifacts.

Comment: It worked!!! Coming from Maven background, I wasted several hours on this.Thank you :) Do you want to create an answer? I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Maven projects artifacts with the dependencies are generated automatically, while for the projects created manually or using dependencies provided by the IvyIDEA plug-in you will have to [configure the artifacts manually](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) and ensure that all the required dependencies are [added to the artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/output-layout-tab.html) that is deployed on the server.